# Метод Include не возвращает значения(EntityFramework Core 2.0)

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework

Есть классы

```
public class Client
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Surname { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public string Street { get; set; }
    public string HouseNumber { get; set; }
    public string Apartment { get; set; }

    public List<Phone> Phones { get; set; }
    public List<Task> Tasks { get; set; }
    public Client()
    {
        Phones = new List<Phone>();
        Tasks = new List<Task>();
    }
}
public class Phone
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int PhoneNumber { get; set; }

    public int ClientId { get; set; }
    public Client Client { get; set; }
}
```

Как только c помощью Include пытаюсь достать телефоны из таблицы, метод get перестает работать и отдает статус failed. Как достать телефоны из таблицы бд и почему не работает?

```
    [HttpGet]
    [ProducesResponseType(typeof(IEnumerable<Client>), 200)]
    public async Task<IActionResult> GetAll()
    {
        var data = await db.Clients.Include(p=>p.Phones).ToListAsync();
        return Ok(data);
    }
```

Comment: вы код копировали, или набирали тут? откуда у вас `Includes` с `s` на конце? или о какой версии EF идет речь?

Comment: Опечатка тут. EF ASP.Net core 2.0

Comment: воспользуйтесь [edit] и измените тэги

Comment: Попробуй db.Clients.Select(x => x).Include(p=>p.Phones).ToListAsync();

Comment: Не помогло. Статус 200, но данные не возвращает(failed to load response data)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вопрос решил. Нашел ответ вот [тут](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data)
Добавил в Startup.cs такой код:

```
 public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
 {
...

services.AddMvc()
    .AddJsonOptions(
        options => options.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore
    );

...
```

}